# Can we use stochastic differential equations analysis on a subspace?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a nonlinear stochastic differential equation of Ito type

$$
dx = f(t,x)dt + g(t,x)dB, \qquad (1)
$$

where B is a p-dimensional Browninan motion, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. In the literature I have found there is always assumed that $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, theorems for the existence and uniqueness of solutions of (1) are derived. Also Lyapunov stability theorems are extended to the stochastic case.

Then I wonder if the results of existence, uniqueness of solutions, and stochastic stability of (1) still apply when $x$ belongs to a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $x\in\Phi\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible to use the definition of forward invariant spaces as in the deterministic case?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but [there is a good deal of theory of SDEs on differentiable manifolds (as I'm linking here, for example, by Ito)](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118764702), which of course can be viewed as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.